# After resize with GParted there is still no space left

Tags: root, partitioning

I had very little space on my ubuntu partition, so i decided to give it more space.
I reduced the /dev/sda7 size, and gave 10GB to /dev/sda5 where my ubuntu installation is.
But strangely (or not) the amount of space available it's the same (the amount used went from about 47.77 i think to 57.44) and it still says that there is no space at the root of file system.
Is there an easy way to fix this? I hear this is related to the assembly point / (where my Ubuntu partition is mounted)

I don't have experience dealing with SO partitions, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[image: cmd]
[image: gparted]

Comment: Whats mounted on the root?

Comment: ubuntu partition is mounted on root

Comment: Try to force fsck on next boot `tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sda5` and reboot. Don't forget afterwards to increase fsck threshold

Comment: Are you housecleaning? https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoverLostDiskSpace

Comment: @Krzysztof Księżyk how can i increase the fsck threshold? thanks

Comment: Can anyone help me? I still havent solved this problem

Comment: I gave up on this and uninstalled Ubuntu for now.

Answer (score 1):

(Ubuntu 18.04.10)
I resized a disk using parted and ran into this because forgot to increase the size of the filesystem. The fix was to use resize2fs.